# How to change the size of a figure environment (not an image inside)

Tags: floats

I have a complicated figure (with sub figures for example).
Is there a way to play with its size, keeping everything in the same proportions and positions? to make them all smaller together etc. instead of changing the size in "include fig" for example (a graph above a picture)

```
   \documentclass{article}

    % if you need to pass options to natbib, use, e.g.:
    % \PassOptionsToPackage{numbers, compress}{natbib}
    % before loading nips_2017
    %
    % to avoid loading the natbib package, add option nonatbib:
    % \usepackage[nonatbib]{nips_2017}


    % to compile a camera-ready version, add the [final] option, e.g.:
    % \usepackage[final]{nips_2017}

    \usepackage{times}
    % For figures
    \usepackage{graphicx} % more modern
    %\usepackage{epsfig} % less modern
    %\usepackage{subfigure} 
    \usepackage{subcaption} 
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,semithick]
    \node[state] (A)                    {$s_0$};
    \node[state] (S) [below of=A] {$s$};
    \node[state,dashed,double] (B) [above of=A] {$\cdots$};
    \node[state,double] (C) [left of=B]         {$s_2$};
    \node[state,double] (D) [left of=C]         {$s_1$};
    \node[state,double] (E) [right of=B]        {$s_{k-1}$};
    \node[state,double] (F) [right of=E]        {$s_k$};
    \path
        (S) edge node {start} (A)
        (A) edge[dashed] (B)
        (A) edge (C)
        (A) edge (D)
        (A) edge (E)
        (A) edge (F);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\label{fig:tree_mdp}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering  
    %   \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{tree}
        \caption{\label{fig:tree_results}}

    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}


    \end{document}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. how you like that sub images appear on page? now are nicely set one above other. and, your figure is far from to be complicated :)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your question is not clear. How you like that sub images appear on page? Now are nicely set one above other (see top figure).

In a case, that the sub images had to be parallel, than you have more possibilities:

- globally change page layout, for example with `\usepackage{geometry}`
- locally change width of figure environment as is done in bottom figure

[image]

In the both case I suggest to correct TikZ picture, i.e. consider positioning syntax as determined by library `positioning`.

```
   \documentclass{article}
%    \usepackage{geometry} % for global setting of page layout
%    \usepackage{times}
    % For figures
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{subcaption}
%    \usepackage{pgf} % <-- unnecessary, it is loaded by tikz
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata, 
                    positioning}% added, for better positioning of image elements

    \usepackage[strict]{changepage}% for local change of page layout
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{showframe}% to see page layout, in real document had to be removed
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, 
    node distance=6mm and 3mm, semithick,
    state/.append style = {inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
    \node[state]        (A)                     {$s_0$};
    \node[state]        (S) [below=of A]        {$s$};
    \node[state,dashed,double] (B) [above=of A] {$\cdots$};
    \node[state,double] (C) [left=of B]         {$s_2$};
    \node[state,double] (D) [left=of C]         {$s_1$};
    \node[state,double] (E) [right=of B]        {$s_{k-1}$};
    \node[state,double] (F) [right=of E]        {$s_k$};
    \path[-stealth',shorten >=1pt]
        (S) edge node {start} (A)
        (A) edge[dashed] (B)
        (A) edge (C)
        (A) edge (D)
        (A) edge (E)
        (A) edge (F);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\label{fig:tree_mdp}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\columnwidth}
        \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{tree}
        \caption{\label{fig:tree_results}}
    \end{subfigure}
        \caption{original figure}
        \end{figure}

        \begin{figure}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance=7mm and 5mm, semithick,
    state/.append style = {inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
    \node[state]        (A)                     {$s_0$};
    \node[state]        (S) [below=of A]        {$s$};
    \node[state,dashed,double] (B) [above=of A] {$\cdots$};
    \node[state,double] (C) [left=of B]         {$s_2$};
    \node[state,double] (D) [left=of C]         {$s_1$};
    \node[state,double] (E) [right=of B]        {$s_{k-1}$};
    \node[state,double] (F) [right=of E]        {$s_k$};
    \path[-stealth',shorten >=1pt]
        (S) edge node {start} (A)
        (A) edge[dashed] (B)
        (A) edge (C)
        (A) edge (D)
        (A) edge (E)
        (A) edge (F);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\label{fig:tree_mdp}}
    \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{tree}
        \caption{\label{fig:tree_results}}
    \end{subfigure}
        \caption{modified figure}
    \end{adjustwidth}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to scale the whole `figure` environment, you can use a `minipage` inside a `\scalebox`, e.g., shrinking it to 70%:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % more modern
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \scalebox{.7}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=1.5cm,semithick]
          \node[state] (A)                    {$s_0$};
          \node[state] (S) [below of=A] {$s$};
          \node[state,dashed,double] (B) [above of=A] {$\cdots$};
          \node[state,double] (C) [left of=B]         {$s_2$};
          \node[state,double] (D) [left of=C]         {$s_1$};
          \node[state,double] (E) [right of=B]        {$s_{k-1}$};
          \node[state,double] (F) [right of=E]        {$s_k$};
          \path
          (S) edge node {start} (A)
          (A) edge[dashed] (B)
          (A) edge (C)
          (A) edge (D)
          (A) edge (E)
          (A) edge (F);

        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{\label{fig:tree_mdp}}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}
        \centering  
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{\label{fig:tree_results}}

      \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
  }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But note, that this will also shrink the line thickness and the thickness of the fonts. So it is not recommended.